# Doubly linked list slice in O(1)?

Tags: python, linked-list, time-complexity

The following code represent an implementation for a slice function.
Assuming that **l1 l2**  are objects of the class Node(**attributes** **id, next, prev**).

I wanted to return the elements between **l1** and **l2** (**l1** and **l2** are included), and then obviously change the prev and the next values because this slice won't be there anymore:

```
def splice(self, l1, l2):
        curr = l1
        s = ""
        while curr.next:
            s += str(curr) + "\n"
            if curr is l2:
                break
            curr = curr.next
        if l1.prev is not None:
           l2.prev = l1.prev
        else:
           self.first = l2.next
           self.first.prev = None

        if l2.next is not None:
           l1.next = l2.next
        else:
            self.last = l2.next
        return s
```

I doubled this codes time complexity is O(1), I think it would be O(n)
because of the While-loop.
Is there anyway I do the same function in O(1)?

Comment: You'll have to process the nodes in between, so it's always gonna be O(n).

Comment: @ForceBru is there anyway to get the slice without looping ?

Comment: Only by using different data structure. Linnked lists will always have O(n) complexity on anything: inserting, deleting, searching.

Comment: @james, if you really need that variable `s`, then no, there's none as you don't know the size of the nodes chain ahead of time. If you didn't need it, you could've returned a new list whose first node'd be `l1` and the last - `l2`. Chopping that sequence off the original list is as easy as setting `l1.prev = l2.next` and `l2.next.prev = l1.prev`.

Comment: @ForceBru thanks for the answer , i'm having this thought now :
if i can make a copy of the linked list without changing the real list , and then just change the last and the first items (nodes) it will actually work . i just need some sort of a deep copy ? please correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: @james, since you've created that class, you can do the copying manually, e.g. just a bunch of `stuffA = stuffB` lines.

Comment: @ForceBru i don't think this will work in this way. because the real list will change, which i don't want . this is why i should somehow copy this linked list obj and then make the required changes on it .,which won't be referred to the real list .

Comment: @james, in that case, you'll have to loop and copy stuff in O(n).

Comment: @ForceBru so i thought about it , instead of creating a copy , i can create new obj inside the same class and just change the last and the first to l1 and l2 . but the question is it is possible to create new empty linked list obj inside the same class "linked list" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to splitting a linked list:

1. Seeking the node to split at
2. Splitting the list

Unfortunately, 1. will always be O(n).  There is no way to 'jump' into a linked list like you can with an array.

The good news is that 2. is an O(1) operation.

What does this mean?

Well, if you take a list and want to slice it after *n* elements, then you need to seek through that many elements and then slice it.

If however you are already performing an operation on the list, you likely have a reference to the list element where you want to make the cut.  In this case, you do not need to seek through the list again.

I used this to good effect in some code I wrote last week.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both parameters are already in the link, I think this can work.

Drawing a picture of it would make it easier to follow

```
[l1.prev]-[l1]-[l1.next]---[l2.prev]-[l2]-[l2.next]
```

The idea is that you want to

1. Set `l1.prev.next = l2.next` to join the list moving left to right
2. Set `l2.next.prev = l1.prev` to join the list moving right to left
3. Set `l1.prev = None` and `l2.next = None` to remove `l1` through `l2` from the initial list
4. Return `l1`, the spliced sub-list.

I might have gotten those steps messed up, but maybe something like this

```
def splice(self, l1, l2):
   before, next = l1.prev, l2.next

   # self.head = ... # TODO: Figure out what this should point at          

   if l2.next:
       l2.next.prev = before if l1 else None  # right-to-left
   if l1.prev:
       l1.prev.next = next if l2 else None # left-to-right

   if l1:
       l1.prev = None # detach <-l1
   if l2:
       l2.next = None # detach l2->

   return l1  # return the sublist
```

Note that finding both l1 and l2 are both O(N) operations

Comment: i'm afraid it won't work correctly . if i understood it right , it will always return the first Node , and the list will be the "should be sliced list"

Comment: If you want to "return the elements between l1 and l2," then you need to return `[l1, l1.next, .... l2.prev, l2]`. You can do that just by returning `l1`, but after you "unlink" `l1.prev`, `l2.next` as well as `l1.prev.next` and `l2.next.prev`. After that you assign `l1.prev.next = l2.next` and `l2.next.prev = l1.prev` to join the initial list back together... At least that's the idea

Comment: unfortunately i tried the code after adding (a , b ,c , d ) and splice(a, c) . splice(a, c) returns just a, and the list (a , b ,c , d ) will be changed to (a , b ,c )

Comment: Well, `self.first`, or whatever it is called would also need to be updated to point to the correct node. In that case `d`, or `l2.next`